# Directly use the fallback character when result of XSLT transformation is not representable in its encoding

Tags: c#, xslt, character-encoding, xslt-1.0, xslcompiledtransform

We have a set of XSLT stylesheets that output to "text". Each stylesheet defines its own output encoding which is different between the stylesheets, e.g.:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" encoding="windows-1252"/>
    ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The stylesheets are fed with various XML data files, some of which may occasionally contain a character that is not representable in the encoding the template declares.
When that happens, an exception occurs upon transformation:

> Unable to translate Unicode character \uXXXX at index N to specified code page.

To quickly reproduce:

```cs
XDocument schema = XDocument.Parse(
    @"<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
        <xsl:output method='text' encoding='windows-1252'/>
        <xsl:template match='root'>
          <xsl:value-of select='.' />
        </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>"
);

XDocument data = XDocument.Parse(
    @"<root>Ψ</root>"
);

XslCompiledTransform transformator = new XslCompiledTransform();
using (var xr = schema.CreateReader())
{
    transformator.Load(schema.CreateReader());
}

using (var output_stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
using (var xr = data.CreateReader())
{
    transformator.Transform(xr, null, output_stream);
    // Error: Unable to translate Unicode character \u03A8 at index 0 to specified code page.
}
```

We are happy to **replace the occasional offending character with a fallback character** (usually that is a `?`). The problem is that the transformator appears to ignore `ReplacementFallback`s in the passed `Encoding` and raises the exception anyway:

```cs
var xml_writer_settings = transformator.OutputSettings.Clone();
var original_encoging = xml_writer_settings.Encoding;

xml_writer_settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(
    original_encoging.CodePage,
    System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback.ReplacementFallback,
    System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback.ReplacementFallback
);

using (var output_stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
using (var xr = data.CreateReader())
using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(output_stream, xml_writer_settings))
{
    transformator.Transform(xr, xw);
    // Same error anyway
}
```

What does work is transforming the template into Unicode, regardless of what it initially requested, and then re-encoding it to its requested encoding:

```cs
var xml_writer_settings = transformator.OutputSettings.Clone();
var original_encoging = xml_writer_settings.Encoding;

var sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var output_stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
using (var xr = data.CreateReader())
using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xml_writer_settings)) // When transforming to StringBuilder, it's always UTF-16
{
    transformator.Transform(xr, xw);

    var b = original_encoging.GetBytes(sb.ToString());  // Default fallback character is used automatically

    output_stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
}
```

but it looks like double work.

**Is there a way to make the `XslCompiledTransform` directly use a fallback character for non-representable characters without the intermediate Unicode step?**

Answer (score 1):

I think it is according to the spec that you get an error: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Text-Output-Method says "If the result tree contains a character that cannot be represented in the encoding that the XSLT processor is using for output, the XSLT processor should signal an error". If you look at the stack trace you get it seems a complex interaction of some XmlWriter implementation and the text encoding classes, but if I try to find the used classes in the online .NET framework reference source code documentation it seems the XmlWriter implementation that is part of it on purpose raises the exception. So unless you implement your own XmlWriter that handles the case differently I think you will not be able to write directly with a particular `xsl:output encoding` to a TextWriter of an encoding that doesn't contain a used output character.

Comment: That is rather interesting. If I have a wrapper for XmlWriter like [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWrappingWriter.cs), I receive the still-unicode text in `WriteString(string text)`. If I re-encode it there and then call `base.WriteString`, it works, otherwise it raises the exception upon `Flush()`. What is interesting is that the exception comes from the `Encoding` instance attached to the original XmlWriter, not from anywhere else. I cannot use `Settings.Encoding.GetBytes(text)`, that is what raises the exception immediately.

Comment: I have to do `Encoding.GetEncoding(Settings.Encoding.CodePage)`, then I get a "more lenient" encoding that is willing to use `?`s, even though when I create the underlying XmlWriter I specifically pass it an encoding that is supposed to do that. Because the exception comes from the encoding and not from the writer itself, I still hope there is a way to trick it into using the right one.

Comment: Which is all because the `Settings.Encoding` has [System.Xml.CharEntityEncoderFallback](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/CharEntityEncoderFallback.cs) as its fallback despite I passed `new System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback("?")` in the settings. Apparently this property is specifically overwritten internally to ignore the passed value.